# Get the width of an image getted by Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, load

I receive images using an Ajax fonction after clicking on a link, so I don't know their widths.. I want to change the css of the images if they are bigger than 650 px. All the images have the same class name `.popup_pics`  so I did :

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('a[class*="popup"]').click(function(){
        showPics(current); //Ajax call

        if ($(".popup_pics").clientWidth > 649) {
            alert($("img.popup_pics").width());
        }
        else {
            alert($("img.popup_pics").width()); 
        }
    }
}
```

But it gives me `undefined` so I think that's because the image isn't loaded yet.
How can I do this ?
Thank you

Comment: Its `.width()`, a function call.

Comment: If all of the images have the same class name, then that selector is going to select them all together. It seems like you probably want to iterate over them and check the width of each one.

Answer (score 1):

Wait for the image to load, and then get its width. Something like this should work:

```
$("img.popup_pics").each(function() {
     var img = $(this),
         src = img.attr('src'),
         image = new Image();

     image.onload = function() {
         // detect width here
         alert(img.width());              
     };

     image.src = src;
});
```

Don't forget to execute this code only after the AJAX has returned successfully and changed the HTML.

Comment: Thank you :) But apparently it doesn't work for me when I put your code after the `showPics(current)` 
I have updated my code to show it fully. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome. If you put the code after showPics is execute, that doesn't guarantee that it will be executed only after the AJAX call has finished. You have to execute the code in the success callback of the AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

.width (http://api.jquery.com/width/) and .height (http://api.jquery.com/height/) are no properties but jquery functions, so this code works:

http://jsfiddle.net/nQvK3/1/

```
$(".popup_pics").each(function(index, domElement) {

    if (domElement.clientWidth > 649) {
        alert(domElement.id + ' is bigger then 649: ' + $("img.popup_pics").width());
    }
    else {
        alert(domElement.id + ' is smaller then 649: ' + $("img.popup_pics").width());   
    }

});
```

I have added some more code, here is the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nQvK3/4/

- first do the ajax call to your images source (i commented it out in the fiddle as i can not do an ajax call to your source)
- when the ajax call is a success we call the showImages function and pass the response object as first parameter
- this function uses jquery each to go through the images array
- for each image we create an image tag and then add the image to the dom
- we finally measure its width and if it is bigger we apply a class to it to resize it

//-- updated code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /*
    var request = $.ajax({
      url: "images.php?gallery_id=1",
      type: "GET",
      data: {id : menuId},
      dataType: "json"
    });

    request.done(function(ajaxImagesResultObject) {*/

        // this is what ajax returns to you, probably an array of objects
        // to test it in your code uncomment the ajax call and comment out the following object
        var ajaxImagesResultObject = { imagesArray: 
            [
                {
                    name: 'stackoverflow small',
                    url: 'http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png'
                },
                {
                    name: 'stackoverflow big',
                    url: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/careers/careers-logo.png'
                }
            ]
        };

        console.log(ajaxImagesResultObject);

        showPics(ajaxImagesResultObject);

    /*});

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });

    */

});

var showPics = function(ajaxImagesResultObject) {

    // foreach image that is contained in the result array
    $.each(ajaxImagesResultObject.imagesArray, function(index, imageData) {

        var imageElement = $('<img src="' + imageData.url + '" id="' + index+1 + '" title="' + imageData.name + '" />');

        // now we add (append) the image inside of the imagesBox element
        $('#imagesBox').append(imageElement);

        // now we check its width and if it is bigger then 649 we add a resize class
        // to save bandwidth images that are too big should get resized on the server not the client
        if ($('#' + index+1).width() > 649) {
            $('#' + index+1).addClass('imageResizer');
        } else {
            // do nothing  
        }

    });

};
```

Comment: This will not check the width of every image with that classname, only the first one.

Comment: @chrisweb thank you :) baut unfortunately even putting it after the ajax call it doesn't work... I've updated my code